# How to disable queue when using addClass?

Tags: jquery

I don't know how to disable the queue when I'm not using .animate() . I think .clearQueue() would work maybe, but I don't know where to put it. Thanks!!

```
$('.one').hover(
  function () {
    $(this).addClass('bigger-outer', 1000);
    $(this).find('.inner').addClass('bigger-inner', 1000);
  }, 
  function () {
    $(this).removeClass('bigger-outer', 1000);
    $(this).find('.inner').removeClass('bigger-inner', 1000)
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`clearQueue` *will* empty the queue, *but* it will leave the *current* animation (if there is any) running.

If you want to stop the current animation as well, see [`stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop), and set both parameters to true (first to clear the queue and the second to jump to the end).

As for where to put them, you'll most likely want it in *both* event handlers;

```
$('.one').hover(
  function () {
    $(this).stop(true, true).addClass('bigger-outer', 1000);
    $(this).find('.inner').addClass('bigger-inner', 1000);
  }, 
  function () {
    $(this).stop(true, true).removeClass('bigger-outer', 1000);
    $(this).find('.inner').removeClass('bigger-inner', 1000)
  }
);
```

**Note** that jQuery's [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass) does not accept a second parameter; it's effect is instantaneous, but [jQuery UI does](http://jqueryui.com/demos/addClass/) (apparently, which is stupid).

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan: It's nothing, but it's what the OP has in his current code. I specify that it's useless in my note.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan: Infact, it seems jQuery UI extends `addClass` to allow a duration; http://jqueryui.com/demos/addClass/

Comment: yeah, the duration parameter in UI is very convenient. Thanks folks

Comment: Okay, so apparently I asked the wrong question. What I am going for is that as soon as mouseOut occurs, the .removeClass will fire. Also, if you hover on and off the element multiple times, only the last thing you do will matter. Thanks.

Comment: So basically if you hover on and off 5 times it wont take 10 seconds to stop moving.

Comment: @watson: Sorry, I had `addClass` and `stop` in the wrong order; see my updated code, it should do what you want!

Answer (score 0):

You can chain `.stop(true)` to clear the animation queue

http://api.jquery.com/stop/